# One button with two functions, Save and Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, razor

When I press the button once, I want to start Upload and Save. I know that to work two functions with with two different buttons, one is Upload and another is Save. Any suggestion? This code works well with two buttons each for one function. That's code. Thanks in advance.

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>

           <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
        </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Create" />

    </fieldset>
       <img src="~/Content/Images/Full/i1.JPG" alt="Sample Image" width="300px" height="200px" />

<!--proba-->
}

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Movies", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
 { 
     <input name="ImageUploaded" type="file">  
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>     
 } 

<!--/proba-->
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can both upload and save in the controller. Otherwise you should use JQuery with Ajax to combine the two. Here is a little suggestion on how you can chain ajax calls.

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("uploadaction", "controller", new AjaxOptions()
{
    OnSuccess = "$(input#save).click()"
})
{
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;" id="upload" />
}

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("saveaction", "controller", new AjaxOptions()
{
    OnSuccess = "route to new url"
})
{
    <input type="submit" style="display:none;" id="save" />
}

<input type="button" onclick="$(input#upload).click()" value="Upload and save" />
```

Comment: mvc reports an error when I'm trying to use ajax...Is there any other way to write this piece of code, maybe with html tag as I wrote in question?

Comment: I suggest you go through this tutorial to make sure you have all the components needed for ajax to work properly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533(v=vs.100).aspx